# How to create a message containing xml prolog declaration

Tags: karate

I am trying to create some dynamic xml messages which will be sent to a service which expects xml. Said service also needs the xml prolog to be specified.

As I want to do a lot of manipulation on the xml I am reading it in a native xml type, however it seems that karate loses the xml prolog information during the conversion (on 0.9.5 and 0.9.6.RC3)

```
Feature: Example

    # https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#sec-prolog-dtd
    Scenario: Example
      Given def nativeXML =
      """
      <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
      <greeting>Hello world</greeting>
      """
      When string nativeToString = nativeXML
      * print nativeToString
      Then assert nativeToString.contains("encoding")
```

Is there a way to preserve the xml prolog?

Code to reproduce this can be found here:  https://github.com/KostasKgr/karate-issues/blob/xml_prolog_to_string/src/test/java/examples/example.feature

Kind regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now there is no other way but to append it manually, which IMO is simple enough. Karate removes it by default during a string conversion, because it gets in the way during Node operations.

```
Given def temp =
"""
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<greeting>Hello world</greeting>
"""
* string body = temp
* def body = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>' + body
* print body
Then assert body.contains("encoding")
```

Comment: Thanks for the response @peter! This seems to work. I am trying to make the steps as succinct as possible and although simple, would like to avoid two extra steps. Since karate does not have another way to achieve this I will continue in the direction you have pointed for now! Cheers

Comment: @KonstantinosKollias thanks - yes from my understanding of the code, this is the best option. I did consider making changes - but there are a lot of teams using the XML support already